# How to set custom cookie data location in Chromium with CEF4Delphi

Tags: delphi, chromium, cef4delphi

In older version of their package Chromium 49.0.2623.110 OldCEF4Delphi there was a function to set custom location of the cookies on the disk `LCookieManager.SetStoragePath(FCookiePath,False,nil);`

but in the newest CEF4Delphi this function is missing, and also the global property **cookie** disappeared, so is it even possible, has it been depreacated for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've just noticed that they combined cache path with cookies so It satisfies me.

Comment: CEF removed the procedure to change the cookies location in the CEF 75.0.7 update back in June and CEF4Delphi had to remove the GlobalCEFApp.cookies property. As you said, the cookies are now stored in the same directory as the cache files.